# asp.net web app - writing data to access or error logs?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

I'm looking for a quick way to log some data - I seem to remember a way to write to the access log, similar to System.Out.Println() but I can't seem to remember how to do it.

I can't attach a debugger, nor can I add additional information to the web app via Response.Write().

Is there a simple way - a single statement with no configuration changes would be ideal - to write to either the error or access logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick way...

Debug.Write("my data to read....");

and read it in real time using sysinterlans DebugView.